# Realloc changes values, why?

Tags: c

```
int **arkadas;
int **komsu;

komsu = malloc( t*sizeof( int* ));
arkadas = malloc( t*sizeof( int* ));

for(i=0; i<t; i++)
{
    x=0;
    komsu[i] = malloc( t*sizeof(int) );
    arkadas[i] = malloc( t*sizeof(int) );//temporary malloc

    for(j=0; j<t; j++)
    {
        komsu[i][j]=fark(kelime[i],kelime[j]);
        if(komsu[i][j]==1)
        {
            komsuSayisi++;
            x++;
            arkadas[i][x]=j;
        }
    }
    if(i==2)
    {
        printf("1. value: %d\n",arkadas[2][2]);
    }
    arkadas[i][0]=x+1;//size here
    if(i==2)
    {
        printf("2. value: %d\n",arkadas[2][2]);
    }
    arkadas[i] = (int *)realloc(arkadas[i],x+1);
    if(i==2)
    {
        printf("3.value: %d\n",arkadas[2][2]);
    }
}
```

Outputs are those:

```
1. value: 150
2. value: 150
3. value: 13243564 (after realloc)
```

I want to convert a matrix into simple matrix, with losing the ones which are `0` in `komsu`. In `arkadas` only `1` ones. But as you can see, after `realloc` values changed. Only one and second one of array stays without changing.

Comment: Your code is unreadable. Please format it properly. The problem will be that you are reading off the end of the arrays.

Comment: Fundamentally your problem is not that the code doesn't work, but that this is no way to code. You cannot carry on like this. You've got no hope of success. You need to organise your code in a clear a structured manner. Your allocations are all over the place. Until you have learnt some basic programming organisation skills, you would be better served by a much higher level language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like with `malloc`, when you call `realloc` you should multiply the number of elements by the size of an element(in this case `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Unless it's `sizeof(char)`, which would be redundant.

Comment: Alternative: With `arkadas[i] = (int *)realloc(arkadas[i],x+1);`, multiply by the size of the *target.  Easier to maintain and avoids the `sizeof(char)` issue: `arkadas[i] = realloc(arkadas[i], (x+1) * sizeof *(arkadas[i]));`